# Converting string to Pascal Case using RegEx

Tags: c#, regex

I am trying to use [RegEx.Replace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.replace?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Text_RegularExpressions_Regex_Replace_System_String_System_String_) to convert a string into Pascal case. RegEx is not necessary, but I thought that maybe it'll be easier. Here are some example test cases I'm trying to convert:

```
simple simon says       => SimpleSimonSays
SIMPLE SIMON SaYs       => SimpleSimonSays
simple_simon_says       => SimpleSimonSays
simple    simon    says => SimpleSimonSays
simpleSimonSays         => SimpleSimonSays
simple___simon___  says => SimpleSimonSays
```

The method I currently have doesn't use RegEx and it works correctly on 4 of the 5 examples above:

```
internal static string GetPascalCaseName(string name)
{
    string s = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.
               TextInfo.ToTitleCase(name.ToLower()).Replace(" ", "").Replace("_", "");

    return s;
}
```

The one example that fails is `simpleSimonSays`. It currently returns `Simplesimonsays` instead of `SimpleSimonSays`. How can I make this work on all 4 scenarios?

**EDIT**

So basically, words are distinguished if there are spaces seperating them, or underscores, or whenever an upper-case character is reached. Also, multiple spaces and/or multiple underscores should be treated as one. Basically spaces and underscores should just be ignored and used as a signal that the next letter should be a capital letter. Like this:

```
simple_____simon___   says => SimpleSimonSays
```

Comment: How will you determine where 'simple' and 'simon', as well as 'simon' and 'says' starts and finishes? I think that is the real issue, how do you determine where one word ends and the other begins for casing if it is a single string with no determining start/finish between each word?

Comment: As far as the single words like `simpleSimonSays`, there is no boundary to extract a case separation. So, unless you're using natural language processing, regex isn't going to ever do that.

Comment: Otherwise, `\b([^\W_]+)(?:[ _]*([^\W_]+))*\b` and use Capture Collections within a delegate callback.

Comment: Think of the single word scenario like this, instead of using _simpleSimonSays_ use `pkrltUdrXywaT`

Comment: @Ingenioushax - I Updated my question. Words are distinguished if there are spaces separating them, or underscores, or whenever an upper-case character is reached (assume it's the start of a new word)

Comment: @sln - I updated my question and hopefully the edit is more clear. For your example, `"pkrltUdrXywaT"` should become `"PkrltUdrXywaT"`.

Comment: `words are distinguished whenever an upper-case character is reached` Then `SIMON` doesn't turn into `Simon`. You actually have to use _non-sencical_ jibberish  test cases to define the rules, not readable words.

Comment: And `SaYs` doesn't turn into `Says`

Comment: @sln - Okay, I'm starting to see what you are saying now. That is a much tougher problem then I originally thought. Like it would almost need to have a dictionary of words and even then, it won't be 100% perfect.

Comment: @Icemanind - Use this [175,000 word dictionary](http://www.regexformat.com/Dnl/_Samples/_Ternary_Tool%20(Dictionary)/___txt/_ASCII_175,000_word_Mix_A-Z_Multi_Lined.txt). You could match the normal way `\b([^\W_]+)(?:[ _]*([^\W_]+))*\b` then in the delegate, upper the first letter, then run the dictionary on each word. If found lower the rest. Ternary Strings to Regex tool create multiple dictionary's divided by [letters](http://www.regexformat.com/Dnl/_Samples/_Ternary_Tool%20(Dictionary)/___txt/) or create your own with the [app](http://www.regexformat.com/version7_files/Rx5_ScrnSht01.jpg).

Comment: @sln - I really don't need to do all that work. All I'm doing is trying to take a table name from a database and make it pascal case so a suitable C# class name can be created, kind of like how Entity Framework does it. Most people will have sensible table names I think (I hope) and I shouldn't have to spell check them or worry about weird characters or anything like that. Pushpesh's answer will probably work for me 97% of the time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a trick for solving your problem. Using regex, split the word and introduce a space within word for words where there is no space or underscore, that are camel case (like this simpleSimonSays). Modify your method to this,

```
internal static string GetPascalCaseName(string name)
{
    if (!name.Contains(" ")) {
        name = Regex.Replace(name, "(?<=[a-z])(?=[A-Z])", " ");
    }
    string s = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.
               TextInfo.ToTitleCase(name.ToLower()).Replace(" ", "").Replace("_", "");

    return s;
}
```

This new line in your method,

```
name = Regex.Replace(name, "(?<=[a-z])(?=[A-Z])", " ");
```

splits the camel case word by introducing a space between them, making them like others where you had no difficultly.

For this input,

```
simpleSimonSays
```

It outputs this,

```
SimpleSimonSays
```

And for rest of the input, it works anyway. This strategy will work even for words where you have partially camel case and partially space or underscore too.

Comment: How should `pkrltUdrXywaT` be capitalized ?

Comment: This almost works. It does not work for my second example though. `SIMPLE SIMON SaYs` becomes `SimpleSimonSaYs` instead of `SimpleSimonSays`

Comment: @sln: I don't see any trouble there. pkrltUdrXywaT would simply become PkrltUdrXywaT where only the first letter changes and becomes capital letter. Did you expect something else?

Comment: @Icemanind: Sorry I missed to see your one case that wasn't working. I've taken care for your 'SIMPLE SIMON SaYs' input and now it would give you your desired result 'SimpleSimonSays'. Please check my updated code. Also, if you have any other case, then let me know. I will further tweak the code and make it work.

Answer (score 0):

If can be version like "abc simpleSimonSays" then it's impossible. Or need to add more rules. Or things like deep learning :)
EDIT:
possible code (but without "abc simpleSimonSays"):

```
var s = "simple__simon_says __ Hi _ _,,, __coolWa";

var s1 = Regex.Replace(s, "[ _,]+", " ");
var s2 = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.TextInfo.ToTitleCase(s1);
var s3 = s2.Replace(" ","");

// s1 = "simple simon says Hi coolWa"
// s2 = "Simple Simon Says Hi Coolwa"
// s3 = "SimpleSimonSaysHiCoolwa"
```

Comment: Words are distinguished if there are spaces separating them, or underscores, or whenever an upper-case character is reached (assume it's the start of a new word). So in your example, it should be `"AbcSimpleSimonSays"`.

Comment: I mean difference   
a)SIMPLE SIMON SaYs => SimpleSimonSays
b)abc simpleSimonSays => AbcSimpleSimonSays
program can't know why 
a)"Y" should become "y"
but b)"S" should left big.
Human understands, but for program - just big letter after small

Answer (score 0):

Here is solution without Regex.  The last one cannot be done.

```
            string[] input = {
                "simple simon says",
                "SIMPLE SIMON SaYs",
                "simple_simon_says",
                "simple    simon    says",
                "simpleSimonSays"
                             };

            var temp = input.Select(x => x.Split(new char[] {' ', '_'}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Select(y => y.Select((z,i) => (i == 0) ? z.ToString().ToUpper() : z.ToString().ToLower()))).ToArray();
            string[] output = temp.Select(x => string.Join("", x.Select(y => string.Join("",y)))).ToArray();
```